# Sketching a graph using completing the square

Tags: geometry

For the question $f(X) = X^2 + 4KX + (3+11K)$, where $K$ is a constant.
given that $K = 1$,
Sketch the graph $y=f(X)$, showing the coordinates of any point at which the graph crosses a coordinate axis.
)"
I get

... $(x+2)^2 - 4^2 + (3 + 11)$ which is equivalent to $(x+2)^2 + 10$
and i get $(-2, 10)$ for the minimum coordinates, however i do not get how the $-2$ value was achieved for the first coordinate value.

Comment: It is the x coordinate for the vertex (in your case a minimum indeed) which can be achieved by performing $-b/(2a)$, a well known formula to find the axis of symmetry of a parabola of the form $y=ax^2+bx+c$

Comment: How did you get $(-2,10)$ for the minimum coordinates? What part of that method did you not trust?

Comment: If you know that the minimum value of $f(x) = (x+2)^2 + 10$ is 10, then what input value for $x$ would give you an output of 10?

Comment: Sorry i don't understand. Could you please explain further ? thanks.

Comment: @DavidK well i know the coordinates are (a,b) where b = +10 but i dont understand how (x+2)^2 = -2 for a. I done this through a walkthrough tutorial on youtube thats how i got the first answer.

Comment: It sounds like you found a method that works but the explanation of _why_ it works either was missing or did not satisfy you. That's a reasonable thing to ask about. It might help clarify the question (by showing what you did _not_ have trouble with) if you edit the question to show the steps you followed (based on the youtube tutorial). You might also look at the answers to http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/325164/help-in-understanding-quadratic-equation -- do they help?

Comment: @DavidK so would the answer be (-2,10) because  -16 + 14 = -2 , and (3 + 11) which is 14 then use -4^2 to get 14 - 4 = 10 ? Is this correct ? And if so, why was this done for the second coordinate 10 ? Thanks.

Comment: It looks like you accidentally squared $2$ twice to get $(x+2)^2 - 4^2 + (3 + 11)$. It should have been $(x+2)^2 - 4 + (3 + 11)$, in which $4 + (3 + 11) = 10$, so when you wrote "equivalent to $(x+2)^2 + 10$" you had a correct formula. It looks like Mick explained the $-2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why we perform the completing square trick is to change the original to the form $y = (x+h)^2 + k$ so that we can deduce the minimum of y.

Since the squared term is always positive, the minimum value of it is 0. This occurs when x = -h. In your case, h = 2.

Answering part

Performing completing square, we have $y = x^2 + 4x + \4 - \4 +(3+11) = (x+2)^2 - 4 + (3+11)= (x+2)^2 + 10$.

The -2 comes directly from setting $x + 2 = 0$.

Comment: so would the answer be (-2,10) because -16 + 14 = -2 , and (3 + 11) which is 14 then use -4^2 to get 14 - 4 = 10 ? Is this correct ? And if so, why was this done for the second coordinate 10 ? Could you please show your working too so I understand this much better? Thanks.

Comment: @Dan See the answering part.

Comment: So where would the + 10 come from ? Thanks.

Comment: @Dan When x = -2, y attains its minimum and $y_{min} = (0)^2 - 4 + 3 + 11 = 10$.

Comment: Thank you so much I understand it now.

Answer (score 0):

Observe that the minimum value of $(x+2)^2$ is 0 at $x=-2$, since  squares are non negative.

Then the minimum value of $(x+2)^2 + 10$ is 10, achieved also at $x=-2$.